# JMeter + HTTP Recorder + Post Operation + Doesn't Post Data

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter HTTP Script Recorder and trying to Post an Object which it does. However, if I re execute the same script by modifying the Body Data of Post Object in order to insert a new record. I see in under `"View Result Tree"` it shows me following two options such as:

- Post XXXX 0 - HTTP/1.1 302 Found
- Post XXXX 1 - HTTP/1.1 200 OK

However, I see no data getting posted/inserted in the application itself.

Post Request:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Have you done any correlation in the script? Can you please include a sample request header, body  in the question. This will help you to get a proper solution.

Comment: Thanks all , I figured this out , I was passing on a static value for a given property in Jason object of HTTP Header , however after setting up a variable that generates random values for this property in Jason object , it worked fine . But still not sure why it failed in the first instance and gave me some unexpected results .

Answer (score 0):

The first response looks suspicious, it's [HTTP 302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) which stands for [Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) so it looks like the application doesn't accept the request and routes you to some other page.

If you need to be authenticated in order to execute the request most probably it redirects you to some form of authentication page.

In the majority of cases such behaviour is caused by:

- Incorrect URL
- Missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)
- Missing or improperly configured [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)